# How can I code a set of numbers to a file so that the file has a minimal size?

Tags: .net

I have to code some algorithm's result in a file. A Result is a list of blocks, each one defined by 5 numbers: 3 ints and 2 floats. The simplest way to code it in a file is of course plain text, for example like this:

```
12 56 81 0.34 1.67 
124 11 76 0.75 6.11 
...
```

It is also the worst way taking the file size into account.

How could I reduce the file size? If these were all integers, I would just convert them to bytes and simply write them as bytes to file and it would reduce the size a bit. But the floats are more problematic.
Any ideas? In C# .NET

Comment: OK, after some comments it becomes clear there is lots of info missing here. 1) Is there a fixed sequence like byte,byte,float,byte? 2) do you just want to write in binary or do you want to compress to bits?

Answer (score 1):

> It is also the worst way taking the file size into account.

Is it?   "12" and "56" would take 2 bytes each in ASCII or UTF-8 encoding. "124" would take 3 bytes, and there would roughly be 1 byte separator per item.  Writing a binary int takes 4 bytes. A similar comparison holds for floats/doubles.

So if the sample is representative of your real data, Text is an easy and compact format. The flexibility is priceless.

Comment: well as far as i know converting 12 to byte would be just one byte: 
00001100... it would take exactly one byte. so it would reduce the size twice. for some numbers - 3 times. and also now i have to write spaces between numbers, and if i was coding bytes, knowing just one number is one byte i wouldn't have to do that. so yes, it would reduce the size

Comment: @agn: How would you know that `00001100 00001100` is the number 12 followed by another 12, and not the single number 3084 ?

Comment: becuase i know that there won't be number bigger than 256... and i would simply always read one byte. i wrote it in some other comment, i forgot i didn't write it in the main topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can always compress the file using a zip library like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

Comment: @agn - and yet, from the statement of the question, a valid solution ;). If you have more constraints, please edit your question and add them.

Answer (score 0):

Binary variable length would be the most compact (i.e. only store 11 bits for numbers that will only need 11 bits), but this rapidly becomes complex because you need to encode both type and length.

How about storing in text, but compressing (e.g. [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)), this will remove almost all (compression isn't perfect) without complex encoding.

Something like:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
using (var gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(gz)) {
  foreach (var num in numbers) {
    writer.Write(num);
    writer.Write(' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: i could do that, i have actually done it before - simple bit coding, i can say for sure that i need max 8 bits for every number (a byte actually) but it's trivial for integers and not so trivial for floats. there were some ways to code floats as bytes but i'm just looking for simpler solution